# Clicking on a SVG button with selenium using python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, svg

Sup,

My idea it's to webscrape all the fixed income information from this website:

https://apprendafixa.com.br/app/investimentos/rendafixa?tipo=cdb

I've already done the code which get's the informations, but i couldn't change the page(check the print screen). As we can see, when you click in the button on the bottom right of the page the link doesn't change and, if you click and hold the buttom, the button class changes too for something close to

```
'mat-pagination-navigation-next mat-icon-button cdk-focused cdk-mouse-focused'.
```

Anyone has any idea to  click in this button using python/ selenium lib?

I've tried `find_element_by_css_selector/xpath` with no results.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round"}

################

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="mat-paginator-navigation-next mat-icon-button" mat-icon-button=""
type="button" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-21" cdk-describedby-host="" aria-label="próxima página">...</button> is not clickable at point (612, 583). Other element would receive
the click: <iframe src="https://app.hubspot.com/conversations-visitor/2392485/threads/utk/d51e40fd3a05488c95b5a7a990f29f49?uuid=8b43149d51cf451b94ad2429df3f2c57&amp;mobile=false&amp;mobileSafari=false&amp;hideWelcomeMessage=false&amp;domain=apprendafixa.com.br&amp;inApp53=false&amp;messagesUtk=d51e40fd3a05488c95b5a7a990f29f49&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fapprendafixa.com.br%2Fapp%2Finvestimentos%2Frendafixa%3Ftipo%3Dcdb%26corretora%3Dbtg%2520pactual%2520digital&amp;inline=false&amp;isFirstVisitorSession=true"></iframe>
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Here is the link of printscreens:

https://imgur.com/a/bil5twA

Comment: Hi Andpoli, I can't test but maybe you're supposed to be clicking the `button` element? css selector = `button[aria-label='próxima página']` or xpath = `//button[@aria-label = 'próxima página']`. I'll post as an answer if that works. I'd also try the `path` which is a child of the `svg`... ie ``button[aria-label='próxima página'] path`